# Intercept exception throw with Guice

Tags: java, exception, internationalization, aop, guice

## Is it possible to intercept any thrown exceptions using [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) ?

The purpose of the interception is for **i18n (internationalization)** of the exception messages. My [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) is ready to rock and I can read the user locale from the HTTP request. I wonder if I can use the **[AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for handling exceptions** (get the error message related to the received code and translate it on the fly).

### Spring

I found it is something possible with Spring by using the [AfterThrowing element](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema-advice-after-throwing). It does not seem exist any equivalent in Guice.

### Constructor interception

I thought to use [constructor interceptor](http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/doc/org/aopalliance/intercept/ConstructorInterceptor.html) on the `Exception` class but Guice can intercept only methods (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781604/intercept-a-constructor-with-google-guice)).

### Java agent

I also found I could use a [Java agent](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076676/learn-java/an-introduction-to-agents.html) to intercept constructor calls and make some delegation. There is the library [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) to simplify it but I don't really want to add a dependency just for this kind of issue. (my apologies, I'm a newbie on Java agents)

### Factory

In a meanwhile, I think to create a factory with assisted inject (with Guice). It means I'll be constrained to use it for throwing exceptions and not simply throw a new instance and let the magic (of the AOP) happen.

*EDIT*

There is a proposition to close this question as a duplicate of "[Guice post execution method interception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195223/guice-post-execution-method-interception)". I would like to highlight the fact that solution requires to intercept all methods of the entire application. I didn't study deeply how cross-cutting is working but I think there is a difference between intercepting all methods and intercepting only exceptions after throwing. I'm wrong? What's the best resource to learn about AOP and this kind of question?

Comment: The answer of the question "[How can I execute code after an intercepted method?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33200814/1832572)" could be a possible solution. _(One day of researches and a solution jumps to my eyes 2 min. after I have posted my question... Not my favorite kind of joke)_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guice post execution method interception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195223/guice-post-execution-method-interception)

Comment: Glad my answer could help you ... I voted to close this question as "duplicate" then. ok?

Comment: @JanGalinski I think have a lack of knowledge about AOP. I edited my question for specifying my viewpoint. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JanGalinski After have rethought to this, it appears every exceptions don't have to be intercepted. I think about internal errors and external library errors that never reach the end-user. I'm sorry to ask you this but can you vote again for a duplicate please? _(I made some research and it seems that delete this thread could be a lost of information)_